# Errors when trying to connect esp8266 to firebase

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide

hello guys i was trying to connect my project to firebase but got this erorrs:

```
d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\Firebase.cpp: In member function 'int FirebaseRequest::sendRequest(const string&, const string&, char*, const string&, const string&)':
d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\Firebase.cpp:78:1: error: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Werror=return-type]
   78 | }
      | ^
d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\Firebase.cpp: In member function 'void FirebaseStream::startStreaming(const string&, const string&, const string&)':
d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\Firebase.cpp:91:16: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
   91 |   analyzeError("STREAM", status, path_with_auth);
      |                ^~~~~~~~
d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp: In member function 'virtual void FirebaseHttpClientEsp8266::begin(const string&)':
d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:47:50: error: no matching function for call to 'begin(const char*, const char [60])'
   47 |     http_.begin(url.c_str(), kFirebaseFingerprint);
      |                                                  ^
In file included from d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:9:
C:\Users\NyK\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:166:10: note: candidate: 'bool HTTPClient::begin(String, uint16_t, String)' (near match)
  166 |     bool begin(String host, uint16_t port, String uri = "/")  __attribute__ ((error("obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClient, host, port, uri)")));
      |          ^~~~~
C:\Users\NyK\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:166:10: note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:
d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:47:30: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'uint16_t' {aka 'short unsigned int'} [-fpermissive]
   47 |     http_.begin(url.c_str(), kFirebaseFingerprint);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                              |
      |                              const char*
In file included from d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:9:
C:\Users\NyK\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:167:10: note: candidate: 'bool HTTPClient::begin(String, const uint8_t*)' (near match)
  167 |     bool begin(String url, const uint8_t httpsFingerprint[20])  __attribute__ ((error("obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClientSecure, ...)")));
      |          ^~~~~
C:\Users\NyK\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:167:10: note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:
d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:47:30: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const uint8_t*' {aka 'const unsigned char*'} [-fpermissive]
   47 |     http_.begin(url.c_str(), kFirebaseFingerprint);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                              |
      |                              const char*
d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp: In member function 'virtual void FirebaseHttpClientEsp8266::begin(const string&, const string&)':
d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:51:60: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const uint8_t*' {aka 'const unsigned char*'} [-fpermissive]
   51 |     http_.begin(host.c_str(), kFirebasePort, path.c_str(), kFirebaseFingerprint);
      |                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                            |
      |                                                            const char*
In file included from d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:9:
C:\Users\NyK\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:168:70: note:   initializing argument 4 of 'bool HTTPClient::begin(String, uint16_t, String, const uint8_t*)'
  168 |     bool begin(String host, uint16_t port, String uri, const uint8_t httpsFingerprint[20])  __attribute__ ((error("obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClientSecure, ...)")));
      |                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus.exe: some warnings being treated as errors

exit status 1

Compilation error: exit status 1
```

i've installed the latest version of esp8266 and **"Firebase Arduino Client Library for ESP8266 By Mobitz"** but the error still occured. please help

here's my full code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include<DHT.h>

#define FIREBASE_HOST "*****firebaseio.com"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "*****UKBpSMo07nUT8ZWYS9"

#define WIFI_SSID "******"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "******"

#define DHTPIN D5
#define DHTTYPE DHT11

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

bool light;
bool fan;

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 10000;

void setup() {
  pinMode(D1, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(500);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID,WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.println("Connecting..");
  
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST,FIREBASE_AUTH);
  dht.begin();

  delay(2000);
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void readDatas(){
  float h=dht.readHumidity();
  float t=dht.readTemperature(); 

  Firebase.setFloat("Data/Temperature:",t);
  Firebase.setFloat("Data/Humidity:",h); 
}

void loop() {
  light = Firebase.getBool("LightStates/switch");
  Serial.println(light);
  if(light==true){
    digitalWrite(D6, HIGH);
  }
  if(light==false){
    digitalWrite(D6, LOW);
  }

  fan = Firebase.getBool("FanStates/switch");
  Serial.println(fan);
  if(fan==true){
    digitalWrite(D7, HIGH);
  }
  if(fan==false){
    digitalWrite(D7, LOW);
  }

  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if(currentMillis-previousMillis>=interval){
    readDatas();
    previousMillis=currentMillis;
  }

}
```

Comment: The library "**Firebase Arduino Client Library for ESP8266 By Mobitz**"  doesn't have `FirebaseArduino.h`. You perhaps installed the wrong library?

Comment: I also installed the firebase master but still didn't work

Comment: I don't know which library is "firebase master". But I think you should select one library and stick to it. I believe "*Firebase Arduino Client Library for ESP8266 By Mobitz*" is pretty well documented. If you decide to use that, first check their examples and make them work. And then start injecting your code into their examples. Wherever you copied your code from I believe it is using an old library that is not maintained anymore and not available in the Arduino Library Manager.

Answer (score 1):

fixed by downgrading my esp8266 version to 2.7